# Commerce Customizable product (Example: add/remove topics for pizza)

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to find a way to give the chance to the customers to "customize
" their products.

Straight example:
Luigi has got a Pizzeria and he would like to sell his pizze online where customers can add or remove topics.

Is there a way to get this option with the basic function of Drupal commerce?
Maybe playing around with products and rules?

This could be very useful for a lot of website type.

I found this module Commerce [Customizable Products](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) , it seems to do half of the job. I can add my topics and then with rules I can update the price. It looks like i cannot show the basic topics. Every pizza has to start empty.

Is there anyone who was had experience with it? Any suggestion?

If someone wanted to build a module, I would like to help with it.

Thanks in advance.

12/09/2012 UPGRADE ---------------------

Using [Customizable Products](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) I've created a new line item with a term reference field.
It will be visible in the product page and will show all the term from that taxonomy.
In the product I've got the term field(manage display: hidden) where the editor can select the pizza toppings.

Now, because the line item will print all the terms I would like to create a function that checks the term in the product and puts a flag on the right line item term.

Then, because customers can add and remove toppings from the pizza, in the view I would like to create another function that check if the user has unflagged the basic toppings and print the sign " - " before the toppings.

So the pizzeria will receive:
Pizza:

-ham

+salami

Ham was in the basic toppings.

What API can I use to get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this Josh Millar video will help.

[Customizable Product with Drupal Commerce: Pizza Store](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9KsyvQZaAY)

Comment: Better later than never :D I'm going to have a look this night.